# Post added by PHP redirects to 404

Tags: php, 404-error

On my blog on http://www.hoopsgifs.com/ you can see the few posts I added.

They are aaded via PHP. The stragen thing is when I click on the post it

does not open the post. The same happens if I added the post over dashboard.

Why?

Comment: What does "added via PHP" mean? Did you import posts somehow? Where is your code?

Comment: Looks like a malware site. Beware.

Comment: "Looks like a malware site. Beware." this is my site where I will post NBA hightlighs...however, I experimented with ad netowork that look like malware, have removed them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at how to use [Using_Permalinks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) in WordPress.

Set your **Common Settings** to **Post Name** and save. When you click save it should [flush_rewrite_rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) but you may need to do that manually.

[image]